# Оборот "не менее чем"

Tags: пунктуация

Твердость гаек должна быть меньше твердости шпилек не менее(,) чем на 20 НВ.

Нужна ли запятая? Кажется, есть правило, что если слова "не менее чем" можно заменить сочетанием "как минимум", то запятая не ставится... Но сомневаюсь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна: **как минимум и не менее чем** определяются как наречные выражения, не требующие постановки знаков препинания.

Только по поводу "как минимум" делается замечание о том, что допускается обособление, если в устной речи делаются паузы.

Из справочника "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации", 2012.

**Примеры:**

В результате этого мероприятия казна недополучила **как минимум** миллиард долларов"

За 2001 год собираемость этого налога возросла на 47 процентов, за 2002 год ожидаем прирост ещё **не менее чем** на 40 процентов.

Но: Управление требует комплекса специальных знаний и, **как минимум**, специального образования (обособление связано с позицией наречного выражения).

Comment: Спасибо большое.