# Ставить ли запятую перед "чем"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Человек, живущий без бед, конечно, знает о них, но воспринимает их менее болезненно, чем другие люди.

Comment: Пользуйтесь окном Поиска по сайту:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424556/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC

Answer (score 2):

**Человек, живущий без бед, конечно, знает о них, но воспринимает их менее болезненно, чем другие люди.**

Запятая ставится, здесь оборот с союзом ЧЕМ имеет значение **градационного сравнения.** В этом случае  в предложении присутствует прилагательное или наречие в сравнительной степени.

http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5315&0a0=1790

§ 2096. Союз *чем*  служит для выражения градационного сравнения, т. е. сравнения по соотношению измеряемого: груша слаще, чем яблоко; белее, чем снег; более холодный, чем всегда.  На темном небе начали мелькать звезды, и странно, мне показалось, что они гораздо **выше,** чем у нас на севере (Лерм.); Здесь было **светлее**, чем в поле (Чех.); Она была, смущена еще **более**, чем я (Катаев);